# how to insert current datetime in the sql command

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

how to insert the current time using ado.net sql command. getting error saying The "conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

code

```
 DateTime NowTime = DateTime.Now;
                string usecase = "manhole";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("insert into sms values('" + usecase + "','" + smsbody + "','" + NowTime + "')", con);
                try
                {
                    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


    columns
    updtd_date is datetime

    query
         INSERT INTO sms (usecase, sms, updtd_date)
VALUES ('manhole','level is low at : 22/01/2018 15:56:20','22/01/2018 16:18:28');
```

Comment: If you use parameters you don't need to worry about date formatting because you are inserting an actual DateTime, not a string that has to be parsed (not to mention the prevention of sql injections).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a parametized query instead of concatenating strings, what you are doing is asking for an SQL Injection. Also, you should dispose commands and connections after use them in order to release memory.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into sms (col1) values(@col1"))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", DateTime.Now);
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the only answer so far that actually addresses the **real** problems with the code in the question. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use The Function `GETDATE()` To Get the System Date and Time.

Change `NowTime`

```
"insert into sms values('" + usecase + "','" + smsbody + "','" + NowTime + "')"
```

To This

```
"insert into sms values('" + usecase + "','" + smsbody + "',GETDATE())"
```

Executing the SQL Statements Like this Can Cause SQL Injection, So I Recommend using Parameter may Be Something Like this

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sms values(@usecase,@smsbody,GETDATE())", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@usecase", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usecase;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@smsbody", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = smsbody;

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Comment: <cough> SQL Injection.. parameters

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. Also, if the SQL server is in a different timezone as compared to the application server, the timestamp would be different here.

Comment: @NisargShah, Yes, I agree With that. Otherwise, he can pass the System Date Time in the 2nd Solutions

Comment: Much better.  Safety first and all that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be specific with the date format in SQL if you inserting a date if you not using paramater:

```
    string nowDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss");
        string sql = "insert into @dateT values('"+nowDate+"')";
```

This results to this in my pc

insert into @dateT values('22 Jan 2018 13:27:04');